# ActionBar кастомизация

Tags: android

Хочу кастомизировать ActionBar: изменить цвет текста, бэкграунд.Сделать пытаюсь через стили, и не получается. В чем подвох? Через код работает, а через xml нет.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

Comment: в манифесте у application прописали  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"?

Comment: да, прописан по умолчанию!

Comment: вам принципиально сделать это через ActionBar? Если нет - есть Toolbar, который проще в реализации и не считается устаревшим.

Comment: Нет, не принципиально, можете показать работающий код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так (через ToolBar):

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
  >

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

      ...любые View

  </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

соответственно сам ToolBar кастомится как любой виджет. При необходимости можно добавить стиль:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

в стилях нужно выключить ActionBar:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

в коде:

```
ToolBar toolbar = (ToolBar) findViewById(R.id.tollbarId);
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menuId);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.nav_con);
```

...и так далее.

Comment: Да, так получается!